# Try to delete entire row from table using delete button in PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

i am trying to delete entire row in table from database using function,
i write delete query in function. but delete button is not working. how can do it

**this is my code**

```
    <?php
include 'conn.php';
$result = ("SELECT * FROM usrdata");
$count = mysqli_query($conn, $result);

echo'<table border=1px>';  // opening table tag
echo'<th>id</th><th>email</th><th>Password</th>';

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($count)) {
// we are running a while loop to print all the rows in a table
    echo'<tr>'; // printing table row
    echo '<td>' . $data['id'] . '</td><td>' . $data['email'] . '</td>  <td>' . $data['password'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="button" name="delete" value="delete"></td>';
}

echo'</tr>'; // closing table row
echo '</table>';

if ($_GET) {
    if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
        delete();
    }
}

function delete() {
    $delete1 = ("DELETE FROM `usrdata` WHERE id = '$id'");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $delete1) or die(mysqli_error());

    echo "record deleted";
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Any error coming?

Comment: the function `delete` has no idea what `$id` is - either pass it as a parameter or declare as global inside the function. That said this is vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: trying both way but doesn't work. i think button click event is not pressed or not work

Comment: @AlivetoDie can you please explain how to submit form inside the while loop. i am creating button in while loop so how can i submit button inside the WHILE LOOP. pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You need to have a form with id of record and submit button to submit something.

2.You need to pass `id` as well as `db comnnection object` to `delete` function.

You have to do it like below:-

```
<?php
    include 'conn.php';
    $result = ("SELECT * FROM usrdata"); 
    $count=mysqli_query($conn,$result);

    echo'<table border=1px>';
    echo'<tr><th>id</th><th>email</th><th>Password</th><th>Action</th></tr>'; 

    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($count)){
        echo'<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$data['id'].'</td><td>'.$data['email'].'</td>  <td>'.$data['password'].'</td>'; 
        echo '<td><form method="post"><input type="hidden" name = "id" value ="'.$data['id'].'"><input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete"></form></td>';//add form with id hidden field and submit button
        echo'</tr>';
    }


    echo '</table>';
?>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
        delete($_POST['id']); //pass the id to function
    }

    function delete($id,$conn)
    { // function with id as a parameter
        $delete1 =("DELETE FROM `usrdata` WHERE id = '$id'");
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$delete1) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

        echo "record deleted";

    }
?>
```

***Note:-*** Your code is wide-open for SQL INJECTION. to prevent from it use `prepared statements`

***Reference:-***

[mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

[PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: @aasifghanchi  glad to help you. I have added note and reference section. Please read and try to change code accordingly to make it free from `SQL INJECTION`

Comment: when i run code without conn.php file in function this give error.  so why add this file inside function and working fine.

Comment: @aasifghanchi  please check my updated answer once again as i have some incorrect HTML structure there. It's corrected now

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate the comment above - the function does not know what the variable $id is as it is not defined within the function. So you can either assign as a parameter. Additionally, which I didn't immediately spot, was that the `delete` function similarly requires the `$conn` variable to be defined either as a parameter or as a global within the function itself.

The generated HTML was incorrect - the closing table row tag NEEDS to be within the loop and the `th` sections should be within a table row.

```
function delete($conn,$id){
    $delete1 =("DELETE FROM `usrdata` WHERE id = '$id'");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$delete1) or die(mysqli_error());
    echo "record deleted";
}
```

or declare as `global` within the function

```
function delete(){
    global $id;
    global $conn;
    $delete1 =("DELETE FROM `usrdata` WHERE id = '$id'");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$delete1) or die(mysqli_error());
    echo "record deleted";
}
```

The variable needs to be defined first, a hidden field in the form with the ID or some other means to define the variable.

Better yet would be to use a `prepared statement` in conjunction with the above so

```
function delete( $conn=false, $id=false ){
    if( $conn && $id ){
        $sql='delete from `usrdata` where id = ?';
        $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
        if( $stmt ){
            $stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
            $result=$stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            echo $result ? 'record deleted' : 'error';
        }
    }
}
```

---

As a possible solution, hastily written so excuse errors, you could perhaps do something like this:

The table is wholly contained within a form ( `delrecord` ) with a single hidden field `id` which is assigned a value by some javascript using the buttons `dataset` attribute `data-id`

```
<?php

    include 'conn.php';
    $result = ("SELECT * FROM usrdata"); 
    $count=mysqli_query( $conn, $result );


    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['id'] ) ){

        function delete( $conn=false, $id=false ){
            if( $conn && $id ){
                $sql='delete from `usrdata` where id = ?';
                $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
                if( $stmt ){
                    $stmt->bind_param('i',$id);
                    $result=$stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                    echo $result ? 'record deleted' : 'error';
                }
            }
        }

        $id=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
        call_user_func( 'delete', $conn, $id );
    }


    echo'
    <form name=\'delrecord\' method=\'post\'>

        <input type=\'hidden\' id=\'h_id\' name=\'id\' />

        <table border=1px>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>email</th>
                <th>Password</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>';

    while( $data = mysqli_fetch_array( $count ) ) {
        echo"
            <tr>
                <td>{$data['id']}</td>
                <td>{$data['email']}</td>
                <td>{$data['password']}</td>
                <td><input data-id='{$data['id']}' type='button' name='delete' value='delete'></td>
            </tr>";
    }

    echo '
        </table>
    </form>

    <script>
        var col=Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll("input[type=\'button\'][name=\'delete\']") );
            col.forEach(function(bttn){
                bttn.onclick=function(event){
                    document.getElementById("h_id").value=this.dataset.id;
                    document.forms.delrecord.submit();
                }.bind(bttn)
            })
    </script>';
?>
```

Comment: trying both way but doesn't work. i think button click click event is not pressed

Comment: do you have a form ( can't see one in the above )? You need to ensure that the variable $id is defined before trying to use the `delete` function which requires this variable

Comment: Additionally - there was an error in the html that was generated - the closing `</tr>` tag needs to be inside the loop other wise you will get an ungodly mess in the HTML and it would definitely not work as expected

Comment: there are errors in the answer above ( the accepted one ) so you will need to edit appropriately